# Using the bevel tool on a single axis

Tags: bevel, axis

I am working on a helmet model which has a recessed lower edge, with a more recessed back closing towards the center. I attempted to use a bevel to obtain this effect, and it was mostly successful, except for the fact that the bevel affected both the x and y axis of the model. My goal with this indent was to have it gradually become less dramatic the farther from the back of the model it moved to, so this did not work for me. How can I apply a bevel *only* to this section, and have that bevel only be applied to the x axis, instead of both the x and y axis?

(Image 1: The beveled surface, which *should* be in line with the straight walls to the far left and right, but is affected by the bevel on both axis)

(Image 2: Reference image of the original model. Notice the bevel on the back of the helmet, which only affects the x axis of the helmet, and fades in closer to the rim of the helmet farther from the very back)

[image: The beveled surface, which should be in line with the straight walls to the far left and right, but is affected by the bevel on both axis]
[image: Reference image of the original model. Notice the bevel on the back of the helmet, which only affects the x axis of the helmet, and fades in closer to the rim of the helmet farther from the very back]

Comment: Hi :). Perhaps bevel isn't the right tool for the job here. Modelling it manually will give you more control.